# Adding the first element lists of tuples

Tags: haskell

I have a structure defined as follows:

```
type P = [(Int, Int)]
```

I need to make a function from lists of that structure, add the items that are in first position in the tuple if the following condition is met: that the second element of the tuple is the same.

```
add :: [P] -> P
add lists = ......
```

E.g.

```
add [[(1,2), (3,0)], [(3,1), (7,0)]]
```

The result would be `[(1,2), (3,1), (10.0)]`.

Since only would add tuples (3.0) with (7.0) because it matches the 0.

Comment: Is it a homework? What is your problem? What have you done so far? What is the output of [[(1,2), (3,0)], [(3,1), (7,0)], [(1,2)]]?

Comment: The output of: [(1,2), (3,0)], [(3,1),(7,0)], [(1,2)]] is: [(2,2), (3,1), (10,0)] I had thought to do something like:
add :: [P] -> P
add [] = Error "Empty list"
add (x: xs) = map (\ [(a, b)] -> sum $ map ax, if b == snd xs)

Answer (score 7):

This is a "keyed" operation, and can be solved quite easily with a little help from the standard library.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
```

`Data.Map` implements finite associative maps -- i.e. `M.Map k a` has a set of keys of type `k`, and to each key it associates a value of type `a`.

The extremely useful function for this kind of problem is [`fromListWith`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3AfromListWith):

```
M.fromListWith :: (a -> a -> a) -> [(k,a)] -> M.Map k a
```

The second argument, the list of `(k,a)` tuples, are simply associations, assocating a given key to a given value.  The first argument is a combining function, which says what to do to the values if duplicate keys appear in the list.

You must also use `M.toList :: M.Map k a -> [(k,a)]`  which gives you back the list of associations stored in the Map.  Here's an example:

```
ghci> M.toList (M.fromListWith (+) [(1,2), (2,3), (1,4), (3,5)])
[(1,6),(2,3),(3,5)]
```

Note how the keys are the *first* elements of the tuples, the opposite of how you have stated your problem.  We have combined `(1,2)` and `(1,4)` into `(1,6)`.  We added because we gave the combining function `(+)`.

This one function solves the brunt of your problem -- the rest is just a little plumbing, which I will leave to you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's decompose this problem.

So you have a list of lists

```
[
  [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
  [(2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 2)]
  [(5, 0), (1, 1), (9, 9)]
]
```

and you want the sum of the vertical first elements if the second elements are all (all? or some?) the same, and the tuple in the first list otherwise (judging by your example, your spec doesn't actually say what happens).

The first thing you should do is `transpose` this list, to get something more suited for our calculation.

```
[
  [(1, 0), (2, 0), (5, 0)]
  [(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 1)]
  [(3, 2), (4, 2), (9, 9)]
]
```

Now the problem is essentially a fold over each of these sublists. So you write a function that does it for one of these lists:

```
collapse :: [(Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int)
```

And then you `map` this function over the entire transposed list:

```
add lists = map collapse $ transpose lists
// or point-free
add = map collapse . transpose
```

Now you only need to write `collapse`.

Comment: collapse tuples = ((sum [a | (a, b) <- tuples]), head [b | (a,b) <- tuples])

This function does not work well because if I put:

add [[(4,2), (2,0)], [(3,1), (7,0)]]

Returns:
[(7,2), (9,0)]

instead of:
[(4,2), (3,1), (9,0)]

This is because the bad elements are inserted into the array.

Comment: I suggest you write it in two parts. First, figure out if all the second elements are equal (try `all (== snd (head tuples)) (map snd tuples)`). If they are all equal, sum up the first elements and combine them with the second element of the first tuple. Otherwise, just use the first tuple. Some useful definitions: `first_element = head tuples; firsts = map fst tuples; seconds = map snd tuples`.

Comment: As a general rules, you'll want to avoid explicit recursion in your code whenever possible. `map`, `filter`, `fold` - these are your friends. You can express most of the stuff you do in a beginner's Haskell class in terms of these three. Also, http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ - the search engine for Haskell. The great thing is that you can search for type signatures, e.g. if you need something to turn a list into a bool, search `[a] -> Bool` and `all` is one of the first results you get.

Comment: I can not think like telling collapse function that add the list items if the second is not the same.
So far I have only this:
collapse :: [(Float, Integer)] -> (Float, Integer)
collapse tuples = ((sum [a | (a, b) <- tuples]), head [b | (a, b) <- tuples])

Comment: There's a construct called `if..then..else` in Haskell. I suggest using that.

Comment: I tried with this but still not working:
collapse tuples = if (allEqual (seconds tuples))
then ((sum [a | (a, b) <- tuples]), head (seconds tuples))
else (0.0, 0)


Separate function:
allEqual [] = True
allEqual [x] = True
allEqual (x: y: xs) = (x == y) && allEqual (y: xs)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to take a list of type `[[(Int, Int)]]` and sum the first element of any tuple that has the same second element. You can completely disregard that it is a list of lists and just `concat` right away, unless the structure of the lists can help you determine which elements should be added (but I have not seem any evidence that would indicate that). Then you get the minimum `snd`, sort the list by the `snd` values, and recurse through the list, calling `span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` which takes a predicate and splits a list at the last element which satisfies the predicate. Since the list is sorted, this will capture all of the tuples with same `snd`. Then we fold over that list of tuples.

```
add :: [[(Int, Int)]] -> [(Int, Int)]
add list = addT (minBound :: Int) $ sortBy sortF (concat list)
    where sortF (_,x) (_,y)
                | x < y  = LT
                | x > y  = GT
                | x == y = EQ
          addT n list = sumFunc $ span (sndIs n) list
              where sndIs n (_,y) = y == n 
                    sumFunc ([],b)= addT (n+1) b
                    sumFunc (a,[])= [(foldr (\(x,y) (w,v) -> (x+w,y)) (0,0) a)]
                    sumFunc (a,b) = (foldr (\(x,y) (w,v) -> (x+w,y)) (0,0) a):(addT (n+1) b)
```

then :

```
> add [[(1,2), (3,0)], [(3,1), (7,0)]]
> [(10,0),(3,1),(1,2)]
```

The only problem is the complexity is very bad (try `add [[(43, minBound :: Int), (10, maxBound :: Int)]]`). If you want to make it faster, you should get all the `snd`s first and only call addT with those, if you are likely to be using this function on values that differ greatly.

Comment: Do not you could simplify a bit more?

Comment: With `on` from `Data.Function` you have `sortF = on compare snd`.

Comment: @Landei: Also `comparing` from `Data.Ord`: `sortF = comparing snd`. :)

Answer (score 1):

After merging and sorting (on second element), you can use a variant of `group(By)` to combine the tuples that have the same second element.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

add :: [P] -> P
add = combine . sortBy (comparing snd) . concat
  where
    combine []     = []
    combine (x:xs) = (fst x + foldr ((+) . fst) 0 ys, snd x) : combine zs
      where
        (ys, zs) = span ((snd x ==) . snd) xs
```

Or you can use `groupBy` to get one list for each distinct `snd` value and fold each of those lists:

```
import Data.Function

add' :: [P] -> P
add' = map sumFst . groupBy ((==) `on` snd) . sortBy (comparing snd) . concat
  where
    sumFst = foldr1 $ \(a, b) (x, _) -> (a+x, b)
    -- or, importing Data.Biapplicative from bifunctors package:
    --sumFst = foldr1 $ (+) `biliftA2` const
```